# Javascript Stack Item with same name and get only highest and lowest price

Tags: javascript

In my code now, he push EVERY Item 5 times cause 5 conditions.

The Problem is, i want to show each item one time with only the Highest and Lowest Price.

Like 
"Item - Price: 100000$ - 1$" 
Each item is there 5 times, in different conditions and different prices.

Here is that where push that items

```
for(var h in ItemsCases) {
                        if(itmID == ItemsCases[h].sku) {
                            items.push({
                                name: ItemsCases[h].name,
                                color: ItemsCases[h].color,
                                rarity: ItemsCases[h].rarity,
                                type: ItemsCases[h].type,
                                image: ItemsCases[h].image,
                                price: parseFloat(ItemsCases[h].price/100).toFixed(2)
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

But than i get everything... but i only will show the highest and lowest price of each item name.

```
if(item.type == 'Factory New') {
                                $html_items[i] += `
                                    <div class="case_item">
                                        <div class="color" style="background-color :` + item.color + `"></div>
                                        <div class="type">` + $type + `</div>
                                        <div class="price">$` + app.format_number(item.price) + `</div>
                                        <div class="img">
                                            <img src="` + item.image + `">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="name">` + item.name.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "").split(' | ')[0] + `</div>
                                        <div class="name2">` + item.name.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "").split(' | ')[1] + `</div>
                                    </div>
                                `;
                            }
```

The if i build with Factory New, than i get only the highest condition, but than i miss the lowest price :/

And i want to show Like Highest price  - Lowest Price like `$100 - $10` But now its showing only the highest...

can someone help me? :/

Comment: could you post a json example of your data structure?

Comment: You might need to store the `priceHigh` and `priceLow` in each item, at the time of `items.push` so you can use it when building HTML. Can you `console.log(ItemsCases)` and post the output of first few items?